# Char * vs NSString *

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, nsstring, char

I am trying to get rid of some confusion when working with C.

Is using `char *name` in some sense the same as working with `NSString *name` in the sense that the pointer still points to the first memory allocation for it?

Ofcourse `NSString` has a bunch of extras but that isnt what I mean, will working with `char *name` allow me to work as if it was a `NSString *name`, so that I could in the future just work with the pointer "name" ?

Comment: There is an initWithCString:encoding: method, which takes a null-terminated C string and gives you an NSString. To go back, use cStringUsingEncoding:

Comment: @Tim Cooper, please don't change my Question titles. ?? :/

Comment: @Inspire48: My question title which Tim decided to edit to his understanding, shows the C vs Obj C. I was purely asking for conceptual reasons when trying to jump from Obj C to C. ;)

Comment: "Edit to *his* understanding?" Tim's not the one asking questions here - maybe you should consider the possibility that it's *you* who has a less-than-perfect understanding of the difference.

Comment: @Sherm: No need to be harsh. I think Helium3 meant that he was trying to highlight the fact that he's trying to grasp the difference between Objective-C and C.

Comment: @Helium3: I realized that you were asking for conceptual, but the answers below covered that nicely. I thought I'd shed some light on the practical, which was not what you were asking—hence why my response is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Chris - You're right, there was absolutely *no* need for Helium3 to respond to harshly to someone's attempt to help him. (Yeah, I know that's not what you meant, I'm just saying - there *are* two sides to this.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is no.

`char*` is meant to point to a simple array of (or single) `char` data values.

```
char* myCharPtr = "This is a string.";
//In memory: myCharPtr contains an address, e.g. |0x27648164|
//at address 0x27648164: |T|h|i|s| |i|s| |a| |s|t|r|i|n|g|.|\0|
```

On the other hand, `NSString *name` will be a pointer to an object which could have *lots* of extras, and you can't rely on where the actual character data is stored, or how. It is not encoded as ASCII (Sherm Pendley down below said it's UTF-16), and it could have extra data like the string's length, etc.

```
NSString* myStringPtr = @"This is an NSString.";
//In memory: myStringPtr contains e.g. |0x27648164|
//at address 0x27648164: |Object data|length|You don't know what else|UTF-16 data|etc.|
```

You alter and access unknown objects through their exposed methods because you don't know how they are formatted in memory, and thus can't access their data directly. (Or because they encapsulate themselves to hide it from you.)

You can still use the `NSString` pointer in future if you declare it as `NSString *name` though. This is what I mean:

```
NSString *name = @"This is a string.";
NSString *sameName = name; //This is pointing to the same object as name
NSLog(@"%@", sameName); //This prints "This is a string.", and if NSStrings were mutable, changing it would change name as well.
                 //They point to the same object.
```

Answer (score 5):

`char*` and `NSString*` are two completely different implementations of strings.

`NSString` can only be used in Objective C (not in plain C), represents immutable strings, is based on Unicode characters and - being an object-oriented class - provides many methods. Furthermore, they are reference counted and always allocated on the heap.

`char*` is just any array of bytes, whose encoding is not well defined, it's mutable and it isn't object-oriented. `char` arrays can be allocated on the heap (with `malloc`) or on the stack. The former requires a call to `free`, while the latter must never be freed.

Comment: I explained (in the title) that I wasnt mixing them and was not talking about the extras for NSString.

Answer (score 2):

> Is using char *name in some sense the
>   same as working with NSString *name in
>   the sense that the pointer still
>   points to the first memory allocation
>   for it?

I think you should regard the NSString* name as a handle to the object rather than a pointer to the object and as such not assume it points to the first memory allocation. I think that would be a better metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

No,

char * is a pointer to an array of characters.  NSString is a pointer to an NSString object.  I cannot find any documentation of it, but I believe that NSString boxes a char *.  Doing name[1] against NSString *name would refer to the 2nd element of an array of NSString objects.

Comment: Internally, NSString actually boxes an array of unichar, a 16-bit data type that uses UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: Sometimes it does anyway.  Sometimes not.   Implementation details.  (Note that you'll never actually have an instance of `NSString` in your app.)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense - a somewhat non-useful sense, to be sure - they *are* the same, in that both are pointer types that refer to a memory address. That similarity turns out to be not very useful in practice though. To make use of either one, you have to take into account the type of "thing" they point to, and how one uses an array of char and an NSString instance is entirely different. Even for something as simple as assignment, one needs to handle the NSString instance in accordance to Cocoa's memory-management rules, using either -copy or -retain instead of a simple "foo = bar" assignment.